# I've been visiting the factory or I've been visiting IN the factory?

Tags: prepositions

Is it acceptable to put the prepositional 'in', in this sentence or it should be dropped?

> I've been visiting the factory.

or

> I've been visiting IN the factory.

Answer (score 4):

(This answer is from the point of view of British English: I have the impression that *visit* is used in other ways in American English, though I don't see anything in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/visit#Verb) to confirm this, so I may be wrong.)

*Visit* means "go to a place to see that place, or go to where a person currently lives or works to meet that person".

So *visit the factory* makes sense, and is normal. *Visit in the factory* makes no sense - but *I've been visiting my colleagues at the factory* is fine.

Comment: *I've been visiting at/in the hospital* is perfectly natural. And you *could* "prime" the context so it would work for a factory. A "community outreach" worker, for example, charged with keeping an eye on "mentally / physically challenged" people. Many of whom might "work" at some local factory that goes out of its way to give those people something useful / rewarding to do. That outreach worker might well say *I'm visiting in the factory today*.

Comment: An intransitive use, @FumbleFingers. I suppose so, once you set the context. It never occurred to me as a possibility, and I suspect that it is not what the OP meant.

Comment: Well, I don't suppose the average learner asking a question like this would be expecting to be told that what he assumes is simply a matter of ***syntax*** actually turns out to be heavily dependent on the ***semantics*** of whichever particular location he refers to in his "visiting" construction. And even we as native speakers don't necessarily think that way. When see the OP's *exact* example, if it does indeed put us in mind of a context where it's perfectly natural, I think we're subconsciously inclined to "blank out" possible alternatives. (Otherwise we'd be constantly confused! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, unfortunately that's quite often what we end up saying - or, worse, it's not even semantics, but the (unpredictable) requirements of the particular words used.

Comment: Curiously though, I draw great satisfaction / comfort from the number of times we (in general, and you and I in particular) *do* have the same apparently "unpredictable" perspective on some obscure aspect of language use! Whereas I suppose what we *should* be looking for here is ways to identify and promote the predictable things. :-(

Answer (score 1):

One usually says "visiting the factory", or "in the factory, visiting."
"Visiting in the factory" is rarely used, but not incorrect. On the other hand, "visiting in a factory" is not uncommon and would emphasize that the visiting for today happens to be in a factory,  and maybe tomorrow the visiting would be on a farm, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

> 1: *I've been visiting the factory*

The thing I visited was the factory itself - probably, but not *necessarily*, there were people at the factory, and I *may* have met some or all of them.

> 2: *I've been visiting **at** the factory*
> (or ***...in** the factory* - the choice of preposition makes no difference)

Means the factory is the place where I performed the action of visiting. With the strong implication that I visited several different *people* there.

I find both the above *reasonably* "idiomatic", because it's easy to imagine #1 being said by a businessman who's thinking about using the factory for some work, and he wants to go and look things over (maybe just the buildings and equipment, at a time when it's unoccupied).

If we change ***factory*** to ***school***, I can easily imagine the parent of a child due to start at the school next term going to check it out in advance. And ***visit*** is a reasonable verb for that context too.

BUT if we change ***factory*** to ***hospital***, I find it *really* hard to imagine #1 making sense. People *don't* normally go to a hospital to check it out before using it (and if they did, ***visit*** might not be a very good way to describe the process). Besides which, visiting *people who are in* hospital is a much more common activity than visiting people in a factory or school.